# Removing input from the DOM and local storage with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a ToDo app in vanilla JavaScript.

My goal is to be able to remove the input data from local storage when the corresponding "X" button has been clicked.

So far, when you click on an X button, the corresponding input field and checkbox are removed from the DOM with this function I created -

```
function removeToDoInput(button, input1, input2, input3) {
    if (allToDoInputs.length > 2) {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            toDoInputContainer.removeChild(input1);
            toDoInputContainer.removeChild(input2);
            toDoInputContainer.removeChild(input3);
            for (let toDoInput = 0; toDoInput < allToDoInputs.length; toDoInput++) {
                for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                    localStorage.removeItem("ToDo " + toDoInput);
                    console.log("test");
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This works fine. But like I mentioned I also need to remove the corresponding input data from local storage.

Here is the 'add-to-do' button functionality. You'll notice the removeToDoInput is called which I don't think is good -

```
function createToDoInput() {
    const newToDoInputCheckbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
    newToDoInputCheckbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    const newToDoInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
    const newXBtn = document.createElement("SPAN");

    toDoInputContainer.appendChild(newToDoInputCheckbox);
    toDoInputContainer.appendChild(newToDoInput);
    toDoInputContainer.appendChild(newXBtn);

    newToDoInputCheckbox.classList.add("checkbox");
    newToDoInput.classList.add("to-do-input");
    newXBtn.classList.add("X");

    newXBtn.innerHTML = "X";

    newXBtn.addEventListener("click", removeToDoInput(newXBtn, newToDoInputCheckbox, newToDoInput, newXBtn));
}
```

And here is the save button functionality -

```
function saveToDoInputs() {
    localStorage.setItem("Title", toDoListTitle.value.trim());
    
        for (let toDoInput = 0; toDoInput < allToDoInputs.length; toDoInput++) {
            if (createToDoInput) {
                localStorage.setItem("ToDo " + toDoInput, allToDoInputs[toDoInput].value.trim());
            }
    }
}
```

Both of these last functions I mentioned are attached to buttons through click event listeners.

How can I delete the input from local storage as well as the DOM?

Comment: Please see my new [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832773/295783)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect and will be called immediately you assign the event handler

```
newXBtn.addEventListener("click", removeToDoInput(newXBtn, newToDoInputCheckbox, newToDoInput, newXBtn));
```

you need

```
newXBtn.addEventListener("click", function() { removeToDoInput(newXBtn, newToDoInputCheckbox, newToDoInput, newXBtn)});
```

or similar

I have redesigned your code and now it

- wraps the elements in their own container
- delegates click and change to the list container
- use relative addressing (closest)
- gives the todo a unique ID and stores it in an object
- retrieves the object from local storage when loading
- adds the object to localStorage when changed

I also added a select all and delete selected

***NOTE*** I have commented the localStorage interaction out because stacksnippets do not allow access to localStorage. Just uncomment them on your page

```js
let todos = {};
// const saveTodos = localStorage.getItem("ToDo");
// if (saveTodos) todos = JSON.parse(saveTodos);

const toDoInputContainer = document.getElementById("toDoInputContainer");
const toggleSelDel = () => {
  document.getElementById("seldel").classList.toggle("hide",Object.keys(todos).length===0); // show if there are actual entries - we can toggle on existense of checkboxes instead
}
const saveAndToggle = (id,why) => {
  // localStorage.setItem("ToDo",JSON.stringify(todos));
  console.log(id, why);
  toggleSelDel()
};
const saveTodo = (id, text) => {
  todos[id] = text;
  saveAndToggle(id,"added")
};
const removeTodo = id => {
  if (todos[id]) {
    delete todos[id];
  }
  saveAndToggle(id,"deleted"); // toggle anyway
};

function createToDoInput() {
  const todoContainer = document.createElement("div");
  todoContainer.id = 'todo' + new Date().getTime(); // unique ID
  const newToDoInputCheckbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newToDoInputCheckbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  const newToDoInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  const newXBtn = document.createElement("SPAN");

  todoContainer.appendChild(newToDoInputCheckbox);
  todoContainer.appendChild(newToDoInput);
  todoContainer.appendChild(newXBtn);

  newToDoInputCheckbox.classList.add("checkbox");
  newToDoInput.classList.add("to-do-input");
  newXBtn.classList.add("X");
  newXBtn.innerHTML = "X";
  toDoInputContainer.appendChild(todoContainer);
}

toDoInputContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("X")) {
    const parent = tgt.closest("div")
    removeTodo(parent.id);
    parent.remove();
  }
});
toDoInputContainer.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("to-do-input")) {
    const id = tgt.closest("div").id;
    if (tgt.value === "") removeTodo(id);
    else saveTodo(id, tgt.value);
  }
});

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", createToDoInput);

toggleSelDel(); // possibly show the select all button

document.getElementById("selAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const checked = this.checked;
  [...toDoInputContainer.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]")].forEach(chk => chk.checked = checked)
});

document.getElementById("delAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
  [...toDoInputContainer.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]:checked")].forEach(chk => {
    const parent = chk.closest("div");
    removeTodo(parent.id);
    parent.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="seldel" class="hide"><label>Select all<input type="checkbox" id="selAll"/></label><button type="button" id="delAll">Delete selected</button></div>
<div id="toDoInputContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to write this. I'm still testing it and digesting how it all works. I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves I made it a little more DRY